# Pre-training model with existing seasonal data for new dataset with maximum limit

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model

I apologise if this is a simple one, I'm not sure if this is not possible or if I'm just not using the right keywords to find the answer;

Say I've got a pizza store, I've been able to successfully run a machine learning model to predict sales in that store and the seasonal changes. Now suppose i want to assume the same seasonal pattern in a brand new store that has only been open for a while. The new store is increasing and i want to use the growth factor of the new store and the seasonal data from the old store.

Another factor is that there is a maximum capacity of production for each store, so i need to be able to set that maximum so that the growth factor doesn't just keep growing beyond what the store can produce.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help point me in the right direction for a library that would achieve these things and what key words I'm possibly missing. My preferred language is Python.

Comment: Don't worry it's not a simple one! It's actually a quite complex problem, I don't think there's any library which can deal with it out of the box. Afaik the general idea would be to train a single model which includes variables which represent the relevant characteristics of the store. in other words the model is not specific to a single store, but it could leverage general patterns across different stores.